# Customizing Stepper Icons in Material-UI for Different States

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm working on a project with Material-UI (MUI), and I'm trying to customize the icons for each step in a Stepper component based on their states (active, non-active, and completed). Specifically, I want to replace the default icons with custom icons or content that better fit my project's design.

I've seen examples of customizing icons for steps, but I'm not sure how to conditionally apply different icons for active, non-active, and completed states.

Here's what I'd like to achieve:

For active steps, I want to use a custom icon (e.g., a checkmark) to indicate that the step is currently active.

For completed steps, I want to use a different custom icon (e.g., a green checkmark) to show that the step has been successfully completed.

For non-active steps, I'd like to use a separate custom icon (e.g., a grayed-out checkmark) to represent steps that are not yet reached.

Could someone please provide a clear and detailed explanation of how to achieve this level of customization in a Material-UI Stepper component? I'm looking for guidance on how to conditionally apply custom icons based on the step's state.

If possible, please include code examples or reference Material-UI components and props that I should be using. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

I expected that, for active steps, the custom "active" icon would be displayed, for completed steps, the "completed" icon, and for non-active steps, the "non-active" icon.

Comment: Find more information about how to ask a good question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.